# Creating a new prolog list using existing elements

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to create a list of the first names of a list of children that are employed. I really cannot for the life of me see why this code that I'm trying shouldn't work. This is using SWI-Prolog.

```
    add(X,L,[L|X]).

    removeEmployed([],[]).
        removeEmployed([Child|List],[UCList]):-
        Child = person(X,_,_,unemployed),
        add(X,UCList,UCList),
        removeEmployed(List,UCList),
        UCList is UCList.
```

Any insight would be appreciated as I'm very new to Prolog. Yes I've checked out other answered similar questions here and tried using their solutions. removeEmployed is used from the following:

```
q17(MFirst, MSurname,UCList, Total):-
    family(_,
        person(MFirst, MSurname, _,_),
        Children),
    total(Children,Total),
    Total>150000,
    removeEmployed(Children,UCList).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Prolog this code

```
...
UCList is UCList.
```

doesn't make sense at all, because is/2 starts arithmetic evaluation of its right hand term (an expression, usually).

More important, variables cannot be 'reassigned'. A variable is either free or bound, but once bound, it cannot change its 'value' (a binding, really).
As a consequence, also this code

```
...
add(X,UCList,UCList),
...
```

seems doomed to fail, or - if UCList would be free - to create a really strange term.
See if you can spot which kind of structure can result from that.

Consider using some higher level predicate, like findall - that will simplify your task. For instance

```
employed(Children, Employed) :-
  findall(C, member(person(C,_,_,employed), Children), Employed).
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion. findall was very useful. As for some of my problems I took a try-anything approach to solving this problem. 

To try and use the add() method that I was going for would you have to then continually use different names for different lists created by add?

Comment: Yes, you must introduce a fresh variable - a binding point - for each new value.